# Styling of ion-side-menu-content

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I want to add css styles to my login page. The application works as:

- ion-side-menus where is:

  ion-side-menu-content inside of it is:

  ```
  ion-nav-view name="content"
  ```

Controller looks like:

```
        .state('myapp.login', {
            url  : "/login",
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: "myApp-core.login.html",
                    controller : 'LoginController'
                }
            }
        })
```

The problem is that when I changed a main css it causes on all sub pages but I want to change **only** my login page (myApp-core.login.html). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest make your own css class "xxx-login" and apply it on html tag?
if you want to extend ionic class, you can use Less, ionic provide all tools to build it.